# Flask get form returns only the first part of the string

Tags: html, forms, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

This is the code I have used in my webpage to get items from a list and display it as radios in my webpage for input.
Html code:

```
{% for item in l %}
        <div>
          <input type="radio" name="value" value={{item}} style="color: white;" />
          <label style="color: white;">{{item}}</label>
          </div>
            
        {% endfor %}
```

Python Code:

```
val = request.form.get('value')
    note = request.form.get('Note')
    print(val)
```

The webpage prints it like:
[image: Webpage photo]

but in the print statement I have written in python. It prints only "from" in the terminal for any radio button I chose because all of them start with from. but when used as a label it renders fully. I cant find the problem here. So can anyone help me in fixing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing quotation marks around the placeholder. With your code this is what's rendered, in effect, for the first item:

```
<input type="radio" name="value" value="from" 0-50 style="color: white;" />
```

The `0-50` is ignored (doesn't have any meaning in this context). Correct code should be:

```
<input type="radio" name="value" value="{{item}}" style="color: white;" />
```